# How can we calculate $Xf$?

Tags: manifolds, vectors, vector-fields

> Let $X$ be the vector field $x \dfrac{∂}{∂x} + y \dfrac{∂}{∂y}$ and $f (x, y, z)$ the function $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ on $R^3$. Compute $Xf$.

Could you give me some hints how we can calculate it?

Comment: Apply the derivatives to $f$ ie $Xf=x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$

Comment: @marwalix $$Xf=x (2x)+y(2y)=2x^2+2y^2$$ Is this correct??

Comment: Yes perfectly correct

Comment: @marwalix Great!! Thank you very much!!! :-)